# Author is not getting message once the page is published in workflow

Tags: workflow, aem

[image]

I am working on a CQ5 workflow implementation which has three steps.

Author creates/updates  the content and initiates the workflow
First level of Approver (We call it Manager) approves this content. If Manager finds content OK he sends this to next level approver (We call it Publisher) to publish via workflow. Though if manager rejects the content , Author gets a message in his inbox.
Now, if Publisher finds the content good he simply publish the content. If he finds any issue - he rejects the content and Author gets a message in his CQ5 ( Thats how it has been configured)

Now we want to send a message to author when the Publisher publishes the content (Technically when the workflow ends). Right now the author only gets the message once content is rejected. Can anybody help us on this ?

PS: We dont want to go with email notifications because of some reasons. We need only CQ5 messages.

Comment: do you want to send message to author's inbox?

Comment: usually the initiator gets a message if the workflow was completed. Though is it one workflow with multiple participant steps or does the manager finish the initial workflow and starts a new publish workflow?
Maybe a screenshot of your workflow would help.

Comment: @Thomas Hi Thomas, I have added the screenshot.

Comment: I have to admit that I am no workflow expert, but yours looks a bit strange to me with all the forking. Shouldn't that be a chain with backsteps if something got rejected? Maybe it is your requirement, but with this each reject finishes the workflow of the item and has to be initiated anew. And then Michal is right you would have to add another step after publish to send out a notification, but again this isn't the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Please notice that 'Publish' step is a Process Step, it does not need any interaction and does not cause the message to appear in author's inbox. It does the job and advances to the next step, which in your case is the Flow End.

You would have to add Participant Step right below Publish step. Same kind of step as you did with Reject.

However, you have to remember that when a workflow reaches for example your Reject step, it does not technically end. Workflow will be in running state unless someone will go into inbox and push it manually to the end. And this is what inbox is for. It is not for information purposes, but rather for taking actions. (In your case, it will be some kind of acknowledge, that something was rejected/accepted)